# for loop with chars java script

Tags: javascript, for-loop, count

Quick question. I am trying to give out numbers with a for loop in JavaScript.
Unfortunately this is not working, if I would code in java then the solution would be replace var with char  and cosole.log with println and got it, but here…   do you have a solution for that ?

```
for ( var i = 'a'; i < 'z'; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: thanks bro, i would never have found it :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
for (var i = 'a'; i !== nextChar('z'); i = nextChar(i)) {
    console.log(i);
}
        
function nextChar(c) {
    return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
}
```